# How to you relate tags to messages and users in a messaging app?

Tags: mongodb, database-normalization, datamodel

I am working on an app with a MongoDB database to send messages between two people and I want each user to create tags for each message. I want users to be able to add new tags or select tags from the list of the ones they've created. Most importantly, once you receive a message with a tag, I want that to be added to your list of tags. Does the following (truncated) data model make sense?

User:

- ID: ID
- Name: STRING
- Tags: Array of TAG-IDs

Message:

- ID: ID
- Sender: USER-ID
- Receiver: USER-ID
- Tags: Array of TAG-IDs

Tag:

- ID: ID
- Label: STRING

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "normalized " & "normalization" & what do they have to do with this question?

Comment: I was asking a two part question. First, how would I do this in MongoDB, which is a document-based DB. Second, more for general learning purposing rather this this specific project, how would I do this in relational database in order to have proper db normalization?

Comment: You haven't addressed my comment, and please ask 1 question per post, and please clarify via edits, not comments. Also research is expected before asking, to be reflected in posts. Also without research or reference to a published method, you're essentially asking for a textbook or tutorial to be rewritten, which is too broad. [ask] [help]

Comment: @philipxy updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you put also the `Label` of Tags into the `Tags` Array. It can help you avoid an extra lookup when you are required to display the `Label`.

Beware the trade-off that you need to update all array entries' `Label` field when there is an update. This could matter depending on your actual scenario.

Here is a good [article](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2) about MongoDB schema design for your reference. It has a similar example to your case.